# Form.Invoke() does not run when form is hidden, 

Tags: c#, multithreading

If I take my C# form (WinForms) and make it not visible:

```
MyForm.Visible = false;
```

and then in a separate thread that I create; the following code executes:

```
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                                          {
                                              ProgressBar2.Visible = false;
                                          }));
```

My application will just freeze and not continue.  If MyForm is visible, the above code in the thread runs fine.  If it is not visible, the code stops running as soon as it reads the "this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()" line.  It does not error out, it just sits there (I set a breakpoint to watch it and it just sits there after the "this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()").

Any idea as to why this will not execute when my form is hidden?  And how I can get around this problem?  I am using "this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()" because I need to be able to set a Progress Bar control on the MainForm as visible (and I must do this on another thread than the main UI thread) and I want to do that regardless if the form is visible or not.

Comment: I don't know the answer but i have similar situation, i think when form object is hidden you can't change visual style of it or it's controls. again just assuming don't know really.

Comment: Hmm... try BeginInvoke().  I don't like issuing synchronous UI updates unless absolutely necessary.  That said, I don't know why your code does not work. It's not possible to focus a control that is disabled/hidden, but a progress bar cannot receive focus anyway.  I'm surprised that an exception is not being thrown somewhere.   What happens if you put a try/catch round the 'ProgressBar2.Visible = false'.?

Comment: @Star - you may well be right, but I'm struggling to find any rationality for it.  If a component cannot be actually rendered because its parent is hidden, then just some internal boolean data member would get changed in the setter method and the component would be rendered correctly when the form is shown again later.  That sound like how it should work, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the form is hidden, I believe the message pump is no longer running. I do know that the Invoke mechanism requires the message pump to be running.

You might be able to work around the issue by setting the opacity to 0 instead of visibility, tho this has its own issues.

Comment: I very much doubt it.  If it became impossible for messages to be dispatched to the form just because it was hidden, it would be impossible to make it visible again!

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your form in an element and set its style="display:none;". Setting visible to false causes the object not to render in the client code.

Comment: The OP is not asking for rendering - changing the 'hidden' property of a component on a hidden form should be OK - it just doesn't get rendered.  Just my 'instinct' on this - don't know the answer.  You may well be correct, it's just that it doesn't feel right..

Comment: It appeared he wanted to act on an object that he did not want visible. Using the client-side hidden vs. server-side visible allows the message pump to continue working since the object is still rendered client side. I agree it doesn't seem completely logical, but it works.