# c# Thread to Thread Exception, loading data to datagridview while using Progressbar on second Form

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am loading data from my datatable into the datagridview of my application.
While doing this I want to inform the User that the App is still running via a second Form where a progressbar shows its progress and a Label which contains information on how many rows were already loaded into the datagrid.

I do know that loading data into the App will freeze my GUI, so I decided to use a second form where I invoke that from my main task.

I call

```
Task task = new Task(LeftJoinTables);
task.Start();
```

then in `LeftJoinTables` I will run this code

```
...
foreach(DataRow rows in FileJoinMail.Rows)
            {
                wfrm.UpdateProgressBar(++i);
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(
                    false, //Checkbox
                    rows["Fullpath"],
                    rows["Filename"],
                    rows["File Size"],
                    rows["UserID"],
                    rows["E-Mail"],
                    rows["Date"]);
                wfrm.ProcInfo($@"Loading Data [{i.ToString()}/{count.ToString()}]");

            }
```

On my second form class I got this method, which invokes the Waitform, which updates the Progressbar and the label with informations

```
public void ProcInfo(string message)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            ProcInfoLabel.Text = message;
        });
    }

public void UpdateProgressBar(int value)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            ProcBar.Value = value;
        });
    }
```

But from this point I got a thread to thread conflict.. I thought using invoke would solve that..

Comment: Can you add the exception that you are getting to the question

Comment: your datagridView1.Rows,Add is also on a background thread, you will need to use invoke on that as well

Comment: Its not in English sorry.. but I translated it:

Invalid thread-to-thread operation: The control 'ProcBar' has been accessed by a thread other than the one in which the control was created.

Comment: Additionally I do not know how many lines you are loading into grid, but loading data into grid once the data is in memory should not take much time. If loading the data from a file into memory is the part taking time, put that in an async method, that would be much cleaner approach

Comment: @peeyushsingh What kind of Invoker Method is this one? The thing is, I am loading 2 tables from 2 excel files via oledb and join them with LINQ. Afterwards I want the joined table to be in the datagrid.

Comment: Is your second form visible when you update it? i.e. have you called wfrm.show() before you start updating it?

Comment: How are you constructing and displaying your second form?  On a background thread, perhaps?

Comment: Please post all code inside `LeftJoinTables` so that we can provide better suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, windows UI (and controls in them) updates using a message pump(queue) and for it to be working the control's handle should have been created. An easy way to ensure this is to make sure your form is visible (and since it is a progress bar, it should be visible).

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wfrm.Show(); // make sure you are making the form visible before updating
        Task task = new Task(LeftJoinTables);
        task.Start();
    }
    private void LeftJoinTables()
    {
        wfrm.ProcInfo("test");
    }
```

Also, your call to update the datagrid would require invoke also.

If you want to force the create of control handle without showing it, you can use the following (taken from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mapo/2011/04/27/forcing-handle-creation-in-a-net-windows-forms-control/):

```
if (!mycontrol.IsHandleCreated)
   {
       // This call forces creation of the control's handle.
       IntPtr handle = mycontrol.Handle;
   }
```

Similar issue:
[Form.Invoke() does not run when form is hidden,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468918/form-invoke-does-not-run-when-form-is-hidden)

Comment: The `Control` does not need to be visible.  However the underlying window's handle must have been created.  Big difference between the two.